# How to Dynamically load EXTERNAL MVVM and NON MVVM controls using Caliburn Micro

Tags: mvvm, user-controls, custom-controls, caliburn.micro

I am loading controls dynamically from the web server from separate XAP files. After creating an instance I want to show them in tab Pages. The controls can be MMVM controls using CM but also non MVVM standard controls.

Before trying the tab I tested to simply show a control dynamically on the page by using:

```
<ContentControl Name="TestControl" />
```

Test control is a property of Type UserControl which is set via creating a new Instance of a dynamically loaded control. Now this gives me an error that it can't find the view. In case of non MVVM controls there is of course no view, so how do I load  a non MVVM control?

I tried to make the test control a MVVM control, but still get the cannot load view error. Makes sense as such instance is not created. If I create an instance of the dynamically loaded view besides the view model, how do I "Add" this so that CM finds it?

Last but not least, how do I bind this to a tab control in Silverlight? The idea is to have a collection of user controls (plugins) which each is rendered in its separate tab page.

Thanks for any help.

(I got this done in no time NOT using MVVM, still not sure if MVVM is worth all the complexity)

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as "mvvm control". MVVM is just a pattern not a control type. Basically, in Caliburn you don't need to work vith UserControls or Views directly, but if you pick the [ViewModel first](http://phurst.com/Blogs/WpfPatterns/ViewModel%20First%20Patterm.html) approach, Caliburn framework should be able to find the matching view for you. In your case since you're loading XAP files dynamically, you need to add them to the list of assemblies Caliburn looks to find a View/ViewModel (and bind them together) and this is done through IAssemblySource interface. According to the documentation [here](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Customizing%20The%20Bootstrapper):

> So, what is AssemblySoure.Instance? This is the place that
>   Caliburn.Micro looks for Views. You can add assemblies to this at any
>   time during your application to make them available to the framework,
>   but there is also a special place to do it in the Bootstrapper.

Comment: By MVVM control I meant a control which has a View and View Model class. Standard controls obviously do not have this and therefore cm does not find any view for my control. So the code which I need to work looks like this:

MyControl myControl=Assembly.Load("SomeDynamicAssembly).GetType("CustomControl") as MyControl;

Public MyControl  CustomControl
{
get{return myControl};
}

<ContentControl x:Name="CustomControl"></ContentControl>

Comment: As I said, you need to add loaded assembly to IAssemblySource and the create the ViewModel instead of creating the view, through the container or whatever. If you've View and ViewModel in your assembly CM will pickup the View and bind it to the ViewModel automatically.

Comment: You still do not understand the problem The dynamically loaded control does not have a view nor a view model. Consider you dynamicall load a button and want to add it to the ContentControl, how do you do this ?